# Generate Word document from SharePoint with ability to include only selected elements

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, word, document-template, quick-parts

I was wondering if this was even possible.

I'm attempting to create a report template for our internal auditors. They go out and do internal audits then put their findings in an audit report that is a Word file. The current audit report template is just a massive plain Word document that has sections (each section has a heading and table) with all the possible findings that could be on the report. Not every section is needed in the report. The auditor would then go into the template and remove whatever sections are not applicable to the specific audit, which is a pain.

The goal here is two-fold:

1. to transition this process into SharePoint and be able to track their audit data
2. to create a dynamic report template that the auditor can generate directly from SharePoint

The cover page for the report template has simple information like location and date so I'm thinking I can create a SharePoint list where the auditor can input that info and when they generate the template, the metadata will be plugged in using Quick Parts. Since the list could be simple, this would cover goal # 1. But I'm having trouble with goal # 2 because for the actual content of the report, I want them to be able to generate a template with ONLY the sections that are applicable to them.

My first question: is there a process that would allow a user to generate a Word template using a SharePoint list but only include the elements that are applicable to them?

Would the answer be building blocks? I discovered that you can use building blocks on Word that would allow users to add certain template elements but I am having trouble figuring out how to use SharePoint to add a building block to a document, and even then, it would only be select building block elements.

My second question: is there a process that would allow users to identify what elements they need in the template via SharePoint that would then trigger the addition of a building block?

My last question: is it even possible to marry the two goals? Would it be cleaner to just use multiple lists (one to track data and one to create report)?

I hope that made sense!! If you're reading this, thank u so much. <3

EDIT: I just realized I probably can't use building blocks for this since users can't see the building blocks I create. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at PowerAutomate for this?  [Create Word Document From SharePoint](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=power+app+to+read+sharepoint+list+and+create+word+document&docid=608023487926850623&mid=57D484765F0D16EBF47A57D484765F0D16EBF47A&view=detail&FORM=VIRE)

Comment: hi there, i am definitely going to use power automate to generate the template but my question is more regarding how to only have certain elements show up in the template.

Comment: This sounds more like a business logic issue than a technical one (not a bad thing): you need a way for each auditor to determine what elements they need, correct? If so, the easiest thing would be to create a different flow for each auditor.